# fade image into page on load

Tags: jquery, fade, pageload

Basically I've been asked to make a website with a logo image fading in before displaying the page ( say 4 seconds display).

From what I can see the best way to do this will be using jQuery. I've seen othe examples where a page fades in after all images are loaded, but how can i do this by specifying an amount of time.

**To Sum up:**

Want to load image in full screen with loading page slightly visible behind (lightbox efect), then fade into fully loaded site content after 4 seconds, regardless of whether the page is loaded or not.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Half of your visitors will have left by the time 4 seconds have passed ?

Answer (score 0):

use `setTimeout` for the delay and call `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`

try this

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('#imageID').fadeIn('slow',function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut('slow') // $('#imageID')".fadeOut('slow',
         },4000);
   })
});
```

you can use modal to display the logo like lightbox effect ... and open and close liekwise...

links for modal..

[simple modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) 
[jquery dialog with true](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

You could start the page off with a div tag that is absolutely positioned on the page, with 100% width and height and then use jquery to "animate" this div's opacity until you get to where you almost cant see it and then you hide the div.

```
<html>
  ..... header content where javascript and what not goes
  <body>
    <div id='introdiv' style="position:absolute;z-index:9999;width:100%;height:100%;">
      .... image goes here
    </div>
    .... other page content goes here.
```

using jQuery Animate, you just do $("#introdiv").animate({......

You'll have to find a way to make sure that the div tag stays hidden on every other request or your image will show up everytime.

If you want to display the image until the page loads, put the animate inside the document.ready function of jQuery.